# How to install the latest version of google earth on ubuntu 12.10 64-bit?

Tags: 12.10

Chris here with a huge problem with the Google earth  latest version.
Gosh.. whenever I try to lunch the app this comes out. I'v Tried this web site nothing worked: (THANK YOU SO MUCH FOR EVEN READING THIS. MAY YOU GUYS HAVE A NICE DAY.

```
christopher@christopher-E4300:~$ google-earth
Google Earth has caught signal 11.

We apologize for the inconvenience, but Google Earth has crashed.
 This is a bug in the program, and should never happen under normal
 circumstances. A bug report and debugging data have been written
 to this text file:

    /home/christopher/.googleearth/crashlogs/crashlog-50cbd67e.txt

Please include this file if you submit a bug report to Google.
```

> https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GoogleEarth#Installing_the_.deb_file_downloaded_from_the_Google_Earth_Website

Here is the content of `/home/christopher/.googleearth/crashlogs/crashlog-50cbd67e.txt`

`Major Version 7 Minor Version 0 Build Number 0001 Build Date Oct 29 2012 Build Time 19:13:39 OS Type 3 OS Major Version 3 OS Minor Version 5 OS Build Version 0 OS Patch Version 0 Crash Signal 11 Crash Time 1355535998 Up Time 0.789556 Stacktrace from glibc: ./libgoogleearth_free.so(+0x1e9cfb)[0xf757dcfb] ./libgoogleearth_free.so(+0x1e9f43)[0xf757df43] [0xf7726400]`

Comment: Have you read the contents of `/home/christopher/.googleearth/crashlogs/crashlog-50cbd67e.txt` to see what the actual error was?

Comment: Hello mate! Major Version 7
Minor Version 0
Build Number 0001
Build Date Oct 29 2012
Build Time 19:13:39
OS Type 3
OS Major Version 3
OS Minor Version 5
OS Build Version 0
OS Patch Version 0
Crash Signal 11
Crash Time 1355535998
Up Time 0.789556

Stacktrace from glibc:
./libgoogleearth_free.so(+0x1e9cfb)[0xf757dcfb]
./libgoogleearth_free.so(+0x1e9f43)[0xf757df43]
[0xf7726400]

Answer (score 1):

A quick google search shows this link: http://www.liberiangeek.net/2012/10/install-google-earth-in-ubuntu-12-10-quantal-quetzal/ which describes how to install Google Earth on Ubuntu 12.10 64-bit addition.  Not quite sure if it is reliable or not, but was the first search.

Jonathan

Comment: this is not what they are looking for

Answer (score 0):

Install the 32-bit version instead. That gave me the true long-term solution to the problem. Download [here](https://dl.google.com/dl/earth/client/current/google-earth-stable_current_i386.deb).

Answer (score 0):

1) Uninstalled Google Earth 64-bit by typing in Terminal

```
sudo dpkg -r google-earth-stable
```

2) Delete the entire ~/.googleearth directory

3) download the 32-bit .deb package from Google and install